# One Dropdown menu to rule them all

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to create a single dropdown menu, not by copying the same pice of code on every page? Using frames is a good method in solving this problem?

Comment: are you looking for only frontend solution? in backend, yes, it's possible

Comment: perhaps you could use a pre-compiler like [ejs](http://www.embeddedjs.com/) and include partials from other files.

Comment: You have to add clarification at "not by copying the same piece of code". If you work with templates, you only have to add/include it and add a script that handles the navigation (only that !) for each webpages you're using.

Comment: I don't work with templates. What I mean is you have let's say 2 pages. Instead of having one time written the code for menu, I put the code at the beginning of both the pages I made.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that creating an html page that contains just the menu, and its links to be all absolute `URL`s could be a solution, although *@Igor Ivancha* is right, and a solution would be using the back-end which is how normally its done.

Say you have  your html page:

```
<nav id="godmenu">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="http://yourdomain.com/page1.html">page1</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://yourdomain.com/page2.html">page2</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://yourdomain.com/page3.html">page3</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

then in each page:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="path to your god menu style" />
</head>

<iframe src="http://yourdomain.com/yourmenu.html"></iframe>
```

Although this is not the best practice, it should work for you if all you need for your page is a dynamic menu, thus not really needing to implement server side code to your website.

Then again, if you don't have that many pages in your site, why not add the menu hard coded in each page,(even though its a pain).

Or just use `PHP` for your back-end which all hosting support.

And another way could be to use `Javascript`

with `jQuery` e.g.

```
$("div").load("http://yourdomain.com/menu.html #godmenu");
```

which would in turn load that specific part of the page into another page.

I believe this to be the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's weird to reference your own site with an iframe, and can bring unexpected behavior.

What you may need is **partial rendering**, a concept that many frontend and backend frameworks inplement.

If you site is static, and you don't have server side rendering, you can do it in the client with JS. A poor man's partial renderer using jquery could look like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $("[render-partial]").each(function(i, el) {
    var
      $el = $(el),
      partialName = $el.attr("render-partial"),
      partial = $("partial[name='" + partialName + "']");

    $el.append(partial.html());
  })
});
```

```css
partial { display: none; }
.red { background-color: red }
.tomato { background-color: tomato }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<partial name="dropdown">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/asdf">asdf</a></li>
    <li><a href="/qwer">qwer</a></li>
    <li><a href="/uiop">uiop</a></li>
  </ul>
</partial>

<div render-partial="dropdown" class="red"></div>
<div render-partial="dropdown" class="tomato"></div>
```

View [live](http://codepen.io/nicooga/pen/ZQKqBx).